# Service Locator Pattern - How to deal with more than one implementation of the same service interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I'm a little confused about the Service Locator design pattern.

It seems to be a very, very basic question regarding this pattern, but I couldn't figure it out: What if I have more than one class implementing some IServiceX interface? How the locator would resolve which instance I'm looking for?

For instance, I could register:

ServiceA implementing IServiceX
ServiceB implementing IServiceX

It seems perfectly possible, but I'm not sure. Let's suppose I have two kinds of Messaging Service (same service interface) and I want to use both implementations during run-time. How the locator would choose between these different implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the fun part. **It's entirely up to you to decide.**

You may traverse your call stack and figure out where the call is coming from, then depending on the caller, return a different implementation.

You may have a Factory method that always goes for a particular implementation.

You may base the instance you return on the time of day, day of week, amount of memory available, ...

It's all up to you!

Comment: Great to know that! Even though the most common usage I've seen around is 1:1 implementation (in samples and tutorials).